# Issue in handling JS popup throwing an exception:org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to selenium web-driver. I am facing a issue 'handling a javascript popup' I click on a button and after clicking that button a popup comes it has a ok button.when I recorded in selenium ide, it shows a (**COMMAND**) assertAlert and (**TARGET**) *A copy of your e-Quote #514106617764 has been generated successfully and sent to your e-mail id.\nPlease continue with your online purchase process. in table(recorded script).so i wrritten following code to handle this popup. i am trying on **getQoute page of igaruntee** of https://buyonline.aegonreligare.com/cordys/buyonlineesales/startiGuarantee.htm?key=websitedirect#

```
try{ 
Actions aa=new Actions(dd);
aa.sendKeys("ENTER");
}


catch(Exception e)
{System.out.println(e)}
```

```js
try
{
 dd.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("check1")));
 WebElement a=dd.findElement(By.id("check1"));
 if(a != null)
 {
  status = 1; 
     System.out.println("iGurantee_Premium Qoute Page " + status);
 }
 else
 {
  status = 0;
  System.out.println("iGurantee_Premium Qoute Page " + status);
 }
 
 Monitoring_FrameWork.SaveResult(tstartTime,"iGurantee_Premium QoutePage ", status,120);
 
}

catch(Exception e)
{
 status = 0; 
 System.out.println(e);
 System.out.println("iGurantee_Premium Qoute Page " + status); 
    
 
}
```

but I am getting an exception as:

```js
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: db7cdba6-b905-49e0-9947-947d18761929
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=18.0}]
iGurantee_Premium Qoute Page 0
Oct 29, 2014 3:46:38 AM org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions findElement
WARNING: WebDriverException thrown by findElement(By.id: check1)
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: Modal dialog present
Build info: version: '2.28.0', revision: '18309', time: '2012-12-11 20:21:45'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'
Session ID: db7cdba6-b905-49e0-9947-947d18761929
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, databaseEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, javascriptEnabled=true, acceptSslCerts=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserName=firefox, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=18.0}]
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createUnhandledAlertException(ErrorHandler.java:168)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:141)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:302)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:331)
 at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:216)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.findElement(ExpectedConditions.java:523)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions.access$0(ExpectedConditions.java:521)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:130)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions$4.apply(ExpectedConditions.java:1)
 at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:204)
 at aegonreligare.test.main(test.java:224)
```

Please tell me how to sovle this.
I even tried using 
Alert a=driver.switchTo.alert;
a.accept(); or a.getText();
but it throws a exception :`There is no alert...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch your window, set focus on the pop up and accept or deny.

```
var alert = Driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

written in c#

Comment: Put some wait before you switching the frame then if that works you can write some custom wait function.

Comment: Thank u so much it worked!!!!!. as per your idea i added some wait before switching to alert.